# Calculating the radius of convergence of a series.

Tags: calculus, real-analysis, elementary-number-theory, limits, power-series

> Let $d_n$ denote the number of divisors of $n^{50}$ then determine the radius of convergence of the series $\sum\limits_{n=1}^{\infty}d_nx^n$.

So obviously we need to calculate the limit of $\frac{d_{n+1}}{d_n}$. I am guessing I need some information about the asymptotic behavior of $d_n$. Any help?

The options given are $1 ,0 , 50 ,\frac{1}{50}$

Comment: Obviously we DO NOT need to calculate the limit of $d_{n+1}/d_n$ (which does not exist).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Note that $d_1=1$, and for all $n \ge 2$, $d_n \le n^{50}$. So $$\frac{1}{R}=\limsup_{n \to \infty}{d_n}^{\frac{1}{n}}$$ and $$1 \le \limsup_{n \to \infty}{d_n}^{\frac{1}{n}} \le \lim_{n \to \infty}(n^{\frac{1}{n}})^{50}=1$$

Answer (score 1):

**Hint:** $1 \leq d_n \leq n^{50}$.

In other words $d_n$ is upper bounded by a power function of $n$. Try to use that when bounding $x^n$, which is an exponential function of $n$.

**Another hint:** For sufficiently large $n$, all $x<1$, and all $k$, one has $n^k<x^n$. In this case $k=50$.

Comment: I don't quite get how I can use the bound $1 \leq d_n \leq n^{50}$ to compute the limit $\frac{d_{n+1}}{d_n}$

Comment: @AloysiusGodinho Don't use the limit.

Comment: Baffling downvote.

Comment: Other users than the downvoter themself can only speculate what was the reason for the downvote. But if you wish to discuss the reason for the downvote, there is a [chatroom explicitly for this purpose](http://chat.stackexchange.com/transcript/message/21818649#21818649).

Comment: @MartinSleziak No thanks, I do not wish to do that (but I would go as far as to wish that you use @).

Comment: You are right @Did, I should probably have pinged you. (Since the downvote was mentioned in your comment and not by the OP.)